# Dependency for driver-class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver is missing

Tags: maven, db2

i added the followinig dependency for my project to connect to the database:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
        <version>4.19.26</version>
    </dependency>
```

Since the connection to my database gets refused (ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001) i tried to add a newer driver

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
        <version>11.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/com/ibm/db2/jcc/db2jcc4/11.1/db2jcc4-11.1.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

I installed the jar with the maven install comand in my project directory. It created a lib folder with everything in it.

However i now get the following error:

Dependency for driver-class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver is missing!

The maven project is definitly able to locate the jar-file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a second dependency you are missing :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
    <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cu</artifactId>
    <version>11.1</version>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/com/ibm/db2/jcc/db2jcc4/11.1/db2jcc_license_cu.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

[Found on nacho4d's blog](https://nacho4d-nacho4d.blogspot.com/2017/04/add-db2-to-maven-project.html)

Comment: And if the Db2-database is remote AND resides either on Z/OS or i-Series (AS/400) then you may additionally need db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar) - the license file , unless you are connecting indirectly via Db2-connect-gateway.

Comment: I think this is only necessary if the connection fails. But in my case it is not even recognizing the driver.